# Is there a conformal map that preserves the Poincaré disc and maps two points $z_1, z_2$ to different points $z_1', z_2'$?

Tags: complex-numbers, hyperbolic-geometry, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation, noneuclidean-geometry

Or does such a map not even exist? I think the wanted map has to merely translate/rotate/maybe reflect the underlying lattice.
I would like to tessellate the hyperbolic plane. My idea is to draw the fundamental polygon in the center of the disk, and then map two vertices at z1 and z2 that are connected by an edge to $z_1'$=-1/2, $z_2'$=1/2, then mirror the fundamental polygon and finally apply the inverse transformation to the lattice. I know I am looking for some möbius transformation, but I fail to find its parameters such that it satisfies my needs.

Comment: Your question is quite imprecise. As currently written, I could answer "yes" by using the map $$f(z) = \begin{cases} z'_1 &\text{if } z=z_1 \\ z_1 &\text{if } z=z'_1 \\ z'_2 &\text{if } z=z_2  \\ z_2 &\text{if } z=z'_2  \\ z &\text{if } z \ne z_1,z'_1,z_2,z'_2 
\end{cases}
$$ which swaps $z_1$ and $z'_1$, and swaps $z_2$ and $z'_2$, and leaves every other point where it is. But I suspect this is not what you intended.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, I was imprecise because I do not have a strong mathematical background and am new to the topic. The map I am looking for has to be conformal, i.e. preserve angles. I think what is needed is something that merely translates/rotates/reflects the underlying lattice. The overall  "order" has to be conserved, meaning if some vertex $A$ has the neighbors $n_1, n_2$ and $n_3$, after applying the transformation this shall remain unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, such a map need not exist.

Also, your problem is worded somewhat ambiguously. At first it seems that $z_1,z_2,z'_1,z'_2$ are points in the Poincare disc $\mathbb D$ itself which is the open disc of radius $1$ centered on $z=0+0i$ and does not contain its boundary circle. But later you refer to $0$, $1$, $\infty$ which are often regarded as points on the boundary "line" of the upper half plane model of the hyperbolic plane (which is metrically isomorphic to the Poincaré disc model, although it is a different point set).

To give a consistent answer, I am going to stick with the Poincare disc $\mathbb D$, and assume that $z_1,z_2,z'_1,z'_2 \in \mathbb D$.

Conformal maps from the Poincaré disc onto itself preserve the hyperbolic metric, i.e. the Poincaré metric, which is given by the line element
$$ds = \frac{2 \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}}{1 - (x^2+y^2)}
$$
Any two points $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb D$ are endpoints of a unique hyperbolic line segment $\overline{z_1 z_2}$, i.e. the unique shortest length path with endpoints $z_1,z_2$, where (hyperbolic) length is determined by integrating $ds$ along that path. Assuming that $z_1 \ne z_2$, that line segment can be visualized in one of two ways: if $z_1,z_2$ lie on a diameter of $\mathbb D$ then $\overline{z_1 z_2}$ is a subsegment of that diameter; otherwise $\overline{z_1 z_2}$ is a circular subarc of the unique circle passing through $z_1,z_2$ that intersects the boundary circle $S^1 = \partial \mathbb D$ in right angles.

Those, basically, are the elements of hyperbolic geometry: points, (hyperbolic) line segments, (hyperbolic) length. Furthermore, the (orientation preserving) rigid motions of this geometry are precisely the conformal transformations of the Poincare disc.

Now one proves that this geometry satisfies all the axioms and theorems of Euclidean geometry, except of course the parallel postulate and theorems which depend on it. In particular, the following theorem is just as true in hyperbolic geometry as it is in Euclidean geometry:

> Two line segments are congruent if and only if they have the same length.

where for purposes of the present discussion, we can take "congruence" to mean existence of a rigid motion taking one line segment to the other.

So, to answer your question, given $z_1,z_2,z'_1,z'_2 \in \mathbb D$, there exists a conformal map taking $z_1 \mapsto z'_1$ and $z_2 \mapsto z'_2$ if and only if the line segments $[z_1,z_2]$ and $[z'_1,z'_2]$ are congruent, if and only if they have the same hyperbolic length.

For example, consider the hyperbolic line segment $[z'_1,z'_2]$ with endpoints $z'_1 = -\frac{1}{2}$ and $z'_2 = \frac{1}{2}$, and the line segment $[z_1,z_2]$ with endpoints $z_1 = - \frac{3}{4}$ and $z_2 = \frac{3}{4}$. Both of those line segments lie on the $x$-axis diameter of $\mathbb D$. The line segment $[z'_1,z'_2]$ is a proper subsegment of $[z_1,z_2]$, so $[z'_1,z'_2]$ is therefore shorter than $[z_1,z_2]$, and those two line segments are therefore *not* congruent. So there is no conformal transformation taking $z_1,z_2$ to $z'_1,z'_2$.

Comment: The example was very illuminating, thank you! Did I understand it right, that if the distance (measured with the poincare metric you mentioned) between two vertices $z_1$ and $z_2 \in \mathbb{D} $ is $r_0$, there is a map taking these points to $\pm \frac{r_0}{2}$, because both line segments are congruent? How would that map look like? Thank you so much!

Edit: I understand the ambiguity concerning the points $0, 1, \infty$ and thus removed that part from my question since it does not provide further meaningful information.

Comment: Be careful, the *hyperbolic* distance between $-\frac{r_0}{2}$ and $\frac{r_0}{2}$ is not equal to $r_0$. Instead it is equal to the integral of $ds$ along the segment $[-\frac{r_0}{2},\frac{r_0}{2}]$. Since $y=0$ and $dy=0$ along that segment, the integral simplifies to $$\int_{-r_0/2}^{r_0/2} \frac{2}{1-x^2}  \, dx$$

Comment: Your question "what would that map look like" is really another question... but, very briefly, it is answered by using the theory of fractional linear transformations, i.e. Möbius transformations, which are the expressions one uses for conformal maps of $\mathbb D$ one itself.

Comment: I see. So I need to solve $\int_{-d}^{+d} dx \frac{2}{1-x^2} = r_0$ for $d$, and then there exists a map taking two points $\in \mathbb{D}$ with hyperbolic distance $r_0$ to $\pm d$ since both segments are congruent. Is that right? Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's right. But, what you should really do is to study hyperbolic geometry, where all these things are worked out. And its beautiful and fun.